# Adding Reference causes post-build to fail

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, log4net, post-build-event, netmodules

I am having trouble adding log4net to my project. I added the reference and set everything up ok, but the build is failing. One of the error messages is complaining about the post-build failing, and the other error messages are saying

> The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you
>   missing *blah blah*?)

But whenever I remove the post-build event, the project builds just fine. How can I fix my post-build event so I can reference log4net? Here is my current post-build (formatted to fit on page w/o scrolling):

```
copy /y "$(SolutionDir)3rdParty\log4net.dll" "$(TargetDir)"

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /target:module 
 /r:"$(SolutionDir)2ndParty\PrintManager.dll" 
 /out:$(TargetDir)PrintModule.netmodule 
 $(ProjectDir)PrinterManaged.cs
```

My project Target Framework is already set to `.NET Framework 4`.

Comment: Does the string $(SolutionDir)3rdParty have a missing "\"?

Comment: @wonko79 No, because the dll is being copied to my output directory just fine.

Comment: When you have referenced log4net in you project why is setting CopyLocal to true for this reference not enough?

Comment: @wonko79 No idea why its not working, no matter what I set `CopyLocal` to, it still fails.

Comment: I meant CopyLocal=true and remove copying in postbuild

Comment: @wonko79 Tried it, still not working. I have the copying in the post build removed because its not helping at all.

Comment: Seems strange to be compiling something in your PostBuild event, but I'm guessing you need to change this to reference log4net.dll (ie add /reference:log4net.dll)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the "Target Framework" (for the Project) to .NET Framework 4 from .NET 4 Client Framework.

Log4Net then works fine.

[image]

EDIT:

May be there's some problem with referencing! 
Try to add the reference correctly.

Comment: Reference is fine, I can browse the code and see all its properties.

Comment: One guess: "The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing blah blah?)" --> May be your code is wrong! Did you add "using log4net" ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your project is built in `.Net Client Profile`. Switch to `.Net full version`.
Log4net uses System.Web which is not included in Client Profile.

Comment: @gwin003 Why are you copying log4net dll ?

Comment: I was hoping it would help, but I get the same result either way. I removed it now.